# Django ORM uses comma as a delimiter?

Tags: python, django

I have some problem with Django, which is somehow Django ORM considers comma as delimiter.

add example code in below.

```
print sub_categorys.description   # is printed as "drum class and drums feature" 
print sub_categorys.image_url     # is printed as ", bongo class no.jpg"
```

but, real database row is description = "drum class and drums feature, bongo class ", and image_url = "no.npg"

please help me out here!
thanks!

additional explain in below, by code.

```
** model.py **
class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField( unique=True )
    description = models.TextField( null=True )
    image_url = models.URLField( null=True )


** views.py > code use to insert data to model **
with open('./classes/resource/model/csv/sub_category_model.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    is_first = True 

    for row in reader:
        if is_first:
            is_first = False
            continue

        sub_category = SubCategory(name=unicode(row[0], 'euc-kr'),
            description=unicode(row[3], 'euc-kr'),
            image_url=unicode(row[4], 'euc-kr'))

        try:
            sub_category.save()
        except Exception, e:
            logger.error(e)
```

Comment: can you post SubCategory model definition, and how you are putting data into the model, and what data you are putting into the model

Comment: column data is string that written by korean. is ok?

Comment: @user3589577 Please add more details and code

Comment: @mamasi add some code, please help! and i edit my name from user3589577 to pjr! don't be confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the ORM that's using the comma as a delimiter, it's `csv.reader`. If you want to import strings that contain commas, you'll have to wrap them in quotation marks. Make sure the CSV file contains the proper quoting. Give your code above, your CSV rows should read something like:

```
foo,bar,baz,"drum class and drums feature, bongo class",no.jpg
```

If that's a problem for some reason, you can choose other delimiters, e.g.:

```
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
```

would take as input:

```
foo|bar|baz|drum class and drums feature, bongo class|no.jpg
```

More examples are available in the [CSV module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! Lastly, there is one more thing I want to ask you. As far as i know, csv file is use comma as delimiter. How can i change delimiter easily?

Comment: Technically, you can use any delimiter you want. How to set that would depend on what tool you are using to generate the CSV file, but for instance in Python you would set it to `|` with `csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|')`. From MySQL, you'd use the `FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'` clause, etc. You can also open your CSV file in a text editor and search/replace.